# How to do conditional checks in cypress

Tags: cypress

I have tree with multiple elements - some elements are inside the header element.

For Eg:

1. Parent Element

   Child element1

   Child Element
2. Axis element

Child elements are visible only when user clicks on the expand option for parent.
I am trying to write something to check if there are child elements exist or not, to determine the given element is header or not.
But cypress test fails compiling, it can't find the child elements.

Is there any way we can conditionally check the presence of these child elements even when the header is not expanded?

As in screenshot these elements are only visible if the tree node for parent expanded.

My intention is to determine whether a given element is header or not, then I can decide what action to do.

Just to clarify my question is - is there way in cypress to check if an element exist and if not I need to do some other actions?

[[image: I want to check the tree node ng][1]]

Answer (score 1):

Conditionally Doing Something.

- Check button is Active before doing somehting.

```js
    cy.get('button').then(($btn) => {
      if ($btn.hasClass('active')) {
        validateChanges();
        logoutUser();
      }
     else{
      // Just Logout
        logoutUser();
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it random when the child is shown. I ask this because you state "*Child elements are visible only when user click on the expand option for parent*"

If the quote is correct it would be more useful to go from there. And do something like this:

```js
cy.get('.div')
  .should('contain.class', 'k-drop-hint')
  .click()
cy.get('.div')
  .should('contain.class', 'tree-node-expanded')
```

This creates a solution to avoid conditional testing.

Comment: @ Mr. J.Thanks, -As you mentioned i clicked on expand option -then i need to see whether there is a class named 'tree group' exists or not. For eg my tree has Demographics ->Gender.Demographics is header and Gender is a normal element under it so when i pass gender -i need to do something else  if(cy.get('.tree-node').contains('Gender',{force: true}).children('.tree-group',{force: true}))
           {
            //do action a
           }

else //do something else

Comment: This is how my code looks like , is there a better way for these type of checks ,Thanks     cy.wrap($header).find('.tree-node-collapsed').click(); if(cy.wrap($header).find('.tree-group')>0)                                                               { cy.log('This is a header') }                                                                                 else{ cy.log('Not a header'); }